# Loading Nib containing UITableView from a UIViewController causes key-value coding compliant error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController setup in storyboard. I'm trying to load a Nib that contains a UITableView. Before I even get to `initWithFrame:` or `awakeFromNib` I get a `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.` error when calling:

`MyView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];`

I know that the connection between my file's owner and the tableView outlet is trying to connect, and fails causing the error. The nib is clean and the outlets don't have any extraneous references. What is causing this error?

Comment: The class connect to the storyboard scene isn't a `UITableViewController` subclass and it doesn't have a property call `tableView`.

Comment: is it impossible to make a nib the delegate and datasource for a tableview?

Comment: No, only subclasses of NSObject can be data source and/or delegate of a table view. A nib is kind of a XML file.

Comment: UIView _is_ a subclass of NSObject... I'm not trying to set the Nib as the data source and delegate, I'm trying to set the Nib's FIle Owner, which contains the outlet... I thought that would be clear

Comment: Check how the outlets are wired up in the nib, and check that your view controller has a tableView IBOutlet defined. If that does't work, post screenshots of the nib in interface builder, showing how the connections are set up from the view(s) to the File's Owner

Comment: @Jpark822 With the current quality of the question on SO nothing is clear anymore. I take each sentence literally.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have come across that error it has been because the view has a reference to an outlet in code that does not exist anymore. Are you sure your view (the storyboard scene or the nib itself) don't have orphan outlet references?